# Parsing Hyphenated xml Tag

Tags: java, apache-commons-digester

can somebody explain me how to parse hyphenated xml tag using commons digest .i have been searching around the net but no luck help me out in this

```
<foo id="1">...
    <bar> 
      <foo-ref id="1"/> 
    </bar>
</foo>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
digester.addObjectCreate("foo-ref", "mypackage.FooRef");
```

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-digester/guide/core.html#doc.Usage